# Python base64 72 chachters per line

Tags: python, base64, line

How can I encode a binary file in base64 and have 72 characters per line?

This is what I have tried but it is not working and i do not know if I am  properly formatting the output so that it can be decoded.

```
import base64

fin = open("/Users/kyle/one_time_pad/encrypt/cipher_text.txt", "rb")
binary_data = fin.read()
fin.close()

b64_data = base64.b64encode(binary_data)
file = b64_data

def split_len(seq, length):
    return [seq[i:i+length] for i in range(0, len(seq), length)]

def organize():
    for a in split_len(file, 72):
        print a

open("/Users/kyle/Desktop/test.txt", "w").write(organize())
```

It gives the error `TypeError: expected a character buffer object`

Comment: In the future, please don't just quote the error, tell us _where_ the error occurs. (The simplest way to do that is by just quoting the whole traceback.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always worth skimming the stdlib before trying to reimplement the wheel. The [`textwrap`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.fill) module is perfect for this purpose:

```
file = b64_data
file72 = textwrap.fill(b64_data, 72)
open("/Users/kyle/Desktop/test.txt", "w").write(file72)
```

---

There are two things wrong with your existing code.

First, you're creating a list of strings from `split_len`, but trying to write it out as a single string with `write`.

Second, your `organize` function tries to fix this… but it actually doesn't return anything, it just prints out a bunch of stuff, so what actually gets passed to `write` is the default return value of `None`.

Anyway, you need to actually accumulate the values into something. You could to that explicitly:

```
def organize(f):
    result = ''
    for a in split_len(f, 72):
        if result: result += '\n'
        result += a
```

… or you could again turn to the included batteries and look for a function that already does this:

```
def organize(f):
    return '\n'.join(f)
```

Or, you could just do the `write` once each time through the loop:

```
with open("/Users/kyle/Desktop/test.txt", "w") as f:
    for a in split_len(file, 72):
        f.write(a + '\n')
```

Or you could just leave it as a list and call `writelines` with that list (but then you'll have to change `split_len` so it adds the `\n` at the end of each line, or call `writelines` on a comprehension that does that for you).

---

A few side notes:

You should always close your files when you open them, and using a `with` statement makes that easier:

```
with open("/Users/kyle/Desktop/test.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(file72)
```

In general, a function like your `organize` that just does something to a global variable that you're only going to call once is not helping anything, because it's no more reusable than just running the code inline. If you want it to be reusable (and debuggable, etc.), have it take a parameter. If you don't need it to be reusable, just write it inline.

Answer (score 2):

```
def organize():
    return "\n".join(split_len(file, 72))
```

should return a string which is what `write` is expecting

on a side note it is probably better to do

```
with open(filename,"w") as f:
        f.write(organize())
```

as this will ensure the file is closed when finished (although tbh your version would likely be garbage collected fairly quick)

Comment: `a in foo` is not a valid generator expression. If you meant `a for a in foo`, that's valid, but it's the same as just using `foo` in the first place. So it's not clear what you were trying to do here.

Comment: whoa I must be tired :P